# Django app treats HTTP request as HttpRequest object, not django-rest Request object

Tags: django, rest, http, http-headers, django-rest-framework

I have the following code

```
 class UserPollPassedView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
      permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
      serializer_class = UsersPollUpdateSerializer

 def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      request.data['date_passed'] = datetime.datetime.now()
      request.data['passed'] = True
      return super(UserPollPassedView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I try to access this method through such curl instrument like hurl.it, I get `QueryDict is immutable` error, because I'm trying to modify the content of `request.data`, assuming that request is Django-rest's `Request` object, but it's not, it is actually native Django `HttpRequest` object. When I explicitly define `Content-type: application\json` in request header, it gives me another `JSON parse error`. When I use httpie tool, everything goes smooth and clean, though it sends the same `application\json` header by default. I suppose, the difference is still in headers, but I can't understand what exactly I should change.

I also tried explicitly typecast `request` from `HttpRequest` to `Request` by adding the following line right before accessing `request.data`

```
request = self.initialize_request(request)
```

but of no use, it gives same `"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"` even if `request` is initially `Request` object from httpie.

Would appreciate any clue

Comment: How do you register your viewset in `urls.py`? Are you using a `Router`? It seems the problem is not in the headers, the `View`'s code is quite straightforward: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L449

Comment: Have you considered avoiding the immutability issue by not modifying the incoming data and instead setting those keys somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think the object is not the DRF request. Since you are using a DRF view, you get a DRF request. Django's own request object doesn't even have a `data` attribute.

Comment: You are right, I was confused about that fact also, but when I try `type(request.data)` with curl.it, it returns `QueryDict`, while when I use httpie it returns simple `Dict`, so go the differences in behavior. The reason I care is that mobile app sends requests similar to curl.it, not httpie.

Answer (score 0):

The `request` variable is definitely holding a DRF `Request` object, and not a Django `HttpRequest` object. You would be getting an error about `data` not existing on the `HttpRequest` if this was not the case.

The problem is that `request.data` is a [`QueryDict` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) when the data is submitted as form data (like through a browser), which should be close to what you would get from `request.POST`/`request.GET`/`request.FILES`. This is probably why you thought it was a Django `HttpRequest`, because this is usually an issue people see after trying to modify any of these objects.

You are trying to modify `request.data` which isn't recommended and should really be treated as an immutable dictionary. Usually this is a sign that you should be setting these keys somewhere else, usually on the serializer layer or by overriding `perform_update` as a hook), instead of modifying the incoming request data.